# Properties of Relations

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Would like to know why those are the answers below.  My book doesn't do a good job explaining. Thanks for the help!:

Determine whether this binary relation is: 1)reflexive, 2)symmetric, 3)antisymmetric, 4)transitive:
The relation R on Z where aRb means a^2=b^2
The answer: 1)reflexive, 2)symmetric, 3)transitive

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not directly about programming or coding.

Comment: It's related to programming; it's a computer science class.  It's called discrete mathematics and it's applications.  Thank you xvan for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Z is the [integer set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer)

> reflexive:
>
> a**R**a for all a in Z
>
> symmetric
>
> a**R**b <-> b**R**a for all a,b in Z
>
> transitive:
>
> a**R**b & b**R**c -> a**R**c for all a,b,c in Z

Just replace R with your operator, the relations are trivial in Z

Comment: I guess I'm just confused because I don't know where the letters are coming from.  In examples I see A={a,b,c,d,e}, but nothing is shown in this question.  Thank you for your response.

Comment: Your letters are any members of Z = { -inf , ... -2, -1, 0 , 1 ,2 , ,3 ... +inf}

Comment: Why does aRb change and how does a^2=b^2 relate to aRb.....Our class had everything else in homework exercises except this.  No wonder I'm clueless.

Comment: imagine R a function `bool R(int a,int b){return a^2 == b^2)`, a is related to b if R(a,b) returns true: `R(2,2)== true, R(-2,2)== true, R(-1,2)==false`

Comment: ohhhhh got it! Thanks.